# Jmeter Test Fragment not working with blazemeter

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I refactored my test plans and created test Fragment(eg. login) in external jmx file so I can use in different test plans.

I used IncludeController in my test plan and refer this external Login Fragment  file.

It works fine if I run jmeter gui, but as soon as I try to run in blazemeter cloud, it fails with error artifact not found. I tried downloading artifacts and external Fragment file is not there.

I came to know, IncludeController get verified before runtime, so there should be some other mechanism to upload these external test Fragment files.

I am sure relative paths for this Fragment jmx file is right as I am also using csv files and that is loading in blazemeter cloud.

Not sure if my approach of using tets Fragment is right?
Do I need to go to test in blazemeter and upload file manually?

Answer (score 0):

As per [How to Manage Large JMeter Scripts With JMeter Test Fragments](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-manage-large-jmeter-scripts-jmeter-test-fragments)

> When uploading the file, simply upload the main script and the respective .jmx files
>       [image: JMeter Test Fragment]
>   Make sure that the main script is selected in ‘JMeter Test Properties’. When BlazeMeter runs the test, it will copy all of the files to the load engine, and the main script will run the ‘browse’ and ‘shop’ files.

So make sure to upload **all** .jmx "module" scripts which you use as Test Fragments along with your main script